# How do i create a shortcut for a command that takes input?

Tags: command-line

Its kind of hard to explain, but what I want, is to make a command that i can activate through a shortcut, that takes the currently selected text, and swaps it for some other text. I thought of using using ctrl+c (with xdotool or something), accessing the clipboard, doing stuff, coping it to the clipboard, than using ctrl+v the same way. But first I need to save whatever is copied in the clipboard and copy it in the end, but than it will probably cause problems when something unexpected is copied (like a large file). so is there a nicer way of doing this?

For example, the command takes a string, and inserts a space between every character. So if I highlight "this sentence" and press, for example, ctrl+shift+q (or whatever I set as the shortcut) the highlighted text (this sentence) is replaced with the text "t h i s s e n t e n c e".

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Here follows a snippet of code that can be a start:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Save current textual clipboard
OLDSELECT="$(xsel --clipboard --output)"

# put selected text in keyboard
sleep 0.1s
SELECTION=$(xsel -b)

# Insert your code that does something with the selection here and save that back to SELECTION
###########
###########
#

# Paste into clipboard

echo $SELECTION | xsel -b -i

# paste snippet
xdotool key --delay 0 shift+Insert
sleep 0.4s   #Firefox needs long delay: 0.2 s not enough - would paste replaced selection
echo "$OLDSELECT" | xsel  --clipboard --input
```

First, the current textselection is saved to OLDSELECT using `xsel` (`xclip` would be an alternative tool). Then, the selected text is put to the clipboard to the variable SELECTION. This is where you then can so something with the content, i.e., insert spaces between each letter.

The end result is put back into the clipboard, then pasted using `xdotool`.

The resulting script can then be assigned a shortcut key.

Comment: Thank you, but like I said, the problem with this solution is that if I had a file or a picture saved to the clipboard, than it would not be saved to OLDSELECT.

Comment: Did you test that actually? I am not sure if another type of clipboard item is lost when you change the textual clipboard. Please test first.